# Join Limit result to joined table without subselect

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have a query joining to tables (user with friends user) and I'd like to limit the second joined table to the first n rows for group.
I read several threads here on stack and this article:
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

I was wondering: is there any change **to not use a subselect**?

Here is a dataset example:

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+----------+-----------------+---------------------+----------+-------------------+------+
| id | created_at | updated_at | deleted_at | status   | username        | mail                | password | recovery_password | pin  |
+----+------------+------------+------------+----------+-----------------+---------------------+----------+-------------------+------+
|  1 | 1412441692 |       NULL |       NULL | enabled  | first.first     | first@first.com     | 111111   | NULL              | 1111 |
|  2 | 1412441692 |       NULL |       NULL | enabled  | second.second   | second@second.com   | 222222   | NULL              | 2222 |
|  3 | 1412441692 |       NULL |       NULL | disabled | third.third     | third@third.com     | 333333   | NULL              | 3333 |
|  4 | 1412441692 |       NULL |       NULL | enabled  | fourth.fourth   | fourth@fourth.com   | 444444   | NULL              | 4444 |
|  5 | 1412441692 |       NULL |       NULL | disabled | fifth.fifth     | fifth@fifth.com     | 555555   | NULL              | 5555 |
|  6 | 1412441692 |       NULL |       NULL | enabled  | sixth.sixth     | sixth@sixth.com     | 666666   | NULL              | 6666 |
|  7 | 1412441692 |       NULL |       NULL | disabled | seventh.seventh | seventh@seventh.com | 777777   | NULL              | 7777 |
+----+------------+------------+------------+----------+-----------------+---------------------+----------+-------------------+------+

+-----+--------+---------+-----+--------+------------+-----------+
| id1 | otype1 | atype   | id2 | otype2 | pushed_at  | popped_at |
+-----+--------+---------+-----+--------+------------+-----------+
|   1 | user   | friends |   2 | user   | 1412441692 |      NULL |
|   1 | user   | friends |   3 | user   | 1412441692 |      NULL |
|   2 | user   | friends |   1 | user   | 1412441692 |      NULL |
|   2 | user   | friends |   6 | user   | 1412441692 |      NULL |
|   4 | user   | friends |   3 | user   | 1412441692 |      NULL |
|   6 | user   | friends |   2 | user   | 1412441692 |      NULL |
|   6 | user   | friends |   7 | user   | 1412441692 |      NULL |
+-----+--------+---------+-----+--------+------------+-----------+
```

And here is the query I'm using right now.

```
SELECT `t1`.`id` AS `id1`, t2.* FROM `User` AS `t1`, `user` AS `t2`, `association` AS `a` WHERE ( t1.id = a.id1 ) AND ( t2.id = a.id2 ) AND ( a.otype1 = "user" ) AND ( a.otype2 = "user") AND ( a.atype = "friends" )

+-----+----+------------+------------+------------+----------+-----------------+---------------------+----------+-------------------+------+
| id1 | id | created_at | updated_at | deleted_at | status   | username        | mail                | password | recovery_password | pin  |
+-----+----+------------+------------+------------+----------+-----------------+---------------------+----------+-------------------+------+
|   1 |  2 | 1412441692 |       NULL |       NULL | enabled  | second.second   | second@second.com   | 222222   | NULL              | 2222 |
|   1 |  3 | 1412441692 |       NULL |       NULL | disabled | third.third     | third@third.com     | 333333   | NULL              | 3333 |
|   2 |  1 | 1412441692 |       NULL |       NULL | enabled  | first.first     | first@first.com     | 111111   | NULL              | 1111 |
|   2 |  6 | 1412441692 |       NULL |       NULL | enabled  | sixth.sixth     | sixth@sixth.com     | 666666   | NULL              | 6666 |
|   4 |  3 | 1412441692 |       NULL |       NULL | disabled | third.third     | third@third.com     | 333333   | NULL              | 3333 |
|   6 |  2 | 1412441692 |       NULL |       NULL | enabled  | second.second   | second@second.com   | 222222   | NULL              | 2222 |
|   6 |  7 | 1412441692 |       NULL |       NULL | disabled | seventh.seventh | seventh@seventh.com | 777777   | NULL              | 7777 |
+-----+----+------------+------------+------------+----------+-----------------+---------------------+----------+-------------------+------+
```

But I'd like to get:

```
+-----+----+------------+------------+------------+----------+-----------------+---------------------+----------+-------------------+------+
| id1 | id | created_at | updated_at | deleted_at | status   | username        | mail                | password | recovery_password | pin  |
+-----+----+------------+------------+------------+----------+-----------------+---------------------+----------+-------------------+------+
|   1 |  2 | 1412441692 |       NULL |       NULL | enabled  | second.second   | second@second.com   | 222222   | NULL              | 2222 |
|   2 |  1 | 1412441692 |       NULL |       NULL | enabled  | first.first     | first@first.com     | 111111   | NULL              | 1111 |
|   4 |  3 | 1412441692 |       NULL |       NULL | disabled | third.third     | third@third.com     | 333333   | NULL              | 3333 |
|   6 |  2 | 1412441692 |       NULL |       NULL | enabled  | second.second   | second@second.com   | 222222   | NULL              | 2222 |
+-----+----+------------+------------+------------+----------+-----------------+---------------------+----------+-------------------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use variables.  First, though, you should write your query more like this:

```
SELECT u1.id AS id1, u2.*
FROM association a JOIN
     User u1
     on u1.id = a.id1 and a.otype1 = 'user' JOIN
     `user` u2
     ON u2.id = a.id2 and a.otype2 = 'user'
WHERE a.atype = 'friends'
```

Note the use of (1) explicit `join` syntax; (2) single quotes for string constants; (3) aliases that are abbreviations for table names; and (4) minimal use of backticks (which just makes queries harder to read.

```
SELECT uu.*
FROM (SELECT u1.id AS id1, u2.*,
             (@rn := if(@id1 = id1, @rn + 1,
                        if(@id1 := id1, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) rn
      FROM association a JOIN
           User u1
           on u1.id = a.id1 and a.otype1 = 'user' JOIN
           `user` u2
           ON u2.id = a.id2 and a.otype2 = 'user' CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @id1 := 0, @rn := 0) vars
      WHERE a.atype = 'friends'
      ORDER BY u1.id
     ) uu
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: ehi gordon, first off thanks. I'm trying to figure out your query. 1) Aren't those subqueries? 2) Is the first select a trick to have numbered rows? 3) Would you please explain a little further the first select and the cross join select? I really thank you for helping me

Comment: There is a big subquery and orders the results by `id`.  Variables are then used to enumerate the rows for each `id`.  The `cross join` and subsequent subquery are just to define variables within the query.